# Printing out mandlebrot in ascii

Tags: c, ascii

I'm trying to print out the ASCII version of mandlebrot in C and it doesn't seem to be working. The main thing is changing the complex c in escapeSteps as the grid changes.

Expected result:
[image: Expected result image]

This is my current code for printing out the result. I think the complex c changing is the reason why it's not working but its just printing out all spaces.

The escapeSteps function checks to see if its in the mandlebrot. C is a complex struct with real and imaginary values.

```
//TILE_SIZE = 512 pixels
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
 for (y = 0; y < TILE_SIZE; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < TILE_SIZE; x++) {
            complex(c) = {(x),(y)};
            if (escapeSteps(c) == 256) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }

        }
        printf("\n");

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: My mandlebrot function is just printing out all spaces instead of printing stars.

Comment: You need to get this down to some kind of  [MCVE] others can run. With what you've shown, one can't even tell whether you're even running over the right part of the complex plane in the first place. Take a look at [ask]

Comment: Well, on second thought, you don't seem to be. You're starting at 0,0 and then stomping off somewhere in giant unit steps. The mandelbrot set is localized right around the origin. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Mandelset_hires.png/644px-Mandelset_hires.png